# Best way to store custom parameters per asset

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a table where I have information about each asset I have (Laptop, Screen, Desktop, Scanners, etc..). I also have another table where I have custom column for each asset (so for a specific desktop I can have a custom column called "Color")... quick shematic :

Assets Table

```
AssetID     Description
---------------------------
1           Desktop HP79801
```

Assets Custom Column

```
AssetID     Column1     Column2
-----------------------------------
1           Color       BluRay ?
```

Now I want to store the value for each column. The way I currently do it for each unit is :

```
AssetID     UnitID      Column1     Column2
-----------------------------------
1           1           Blue        Yes
1           2           Blue        No
1           3           Black       No
1           4           Blue        Yes
```

Now my question, is there a more efficent way to do this and how can I increase the number of column to infinity in an efficent way also ? Is it possible ?

In the end, how to store custom product attributes with effecienty ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Assets custom column is not normalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes.

What you have there isn't scalable in the slightest. What you want is to have a table for your assets, a table for the custom parameters and a "link" table. Then, enter multiple values into your link table rather than multiple columns.

As an example:

Assets Table

```
AssetID     Description
---------------------------
1           Desktop HP79801
```

Attributes Column

```
AssetAttr       Column1     
-----------------------------------
1               Color
2               Size
```

Link table

```
AssetID     UnitID      AttrId        AttrValue 
-----------------------------------
1           1           1             Blue
1           1           2             Big
1           2           1             Orange
1           2           2             Giant
```

If your attributes are all model specific though, you may also want to add a `AssetId` column to your assets custom column, but I wouldn't personally do that unless none of your assets at all shared attributes.

You may also want to tag this further. You may want to annotate your attributes table with a data type, and maybe have another table related to the attributes table holding the possible data values, then, in your link table, insert the ID of the entry from the aforementioned table.

Comment: I'd do it slightly differently, so you'll have more control over your attributes and their values.  See this post from earlier today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710054/mysql-best-way-to-manage-product-sizes/12713221#12713221

Comment: @AlainCollins - if each attrbute wasn't wildly different (and there wasn't a need for "free text"), I'd probably do it that way too. It's basically what I tried to convey in my edit at the bottom though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will use specific attribute for each asset, so this concept is fine with me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a schema less db altogether. My favorite is [Mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/). Another option would be [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or one of the many key-value databases out there.

Not to start a noSQL war here but these databases handle situations like that a lot more gracefully - a single document could store all that data and be retrieved without any joins or views.